# No known class method for selector 'saveData', как исправить?

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

в FirstAppDelegate.m
я пытаюсь прописать метод сохранения:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{   
    [SecondViewController saveData];
}
```

который находиться в SecondViewController, нo почему то не получаеться. Пишет (No known class method for selector 'saveData').

подскажите как исправить этот недуг?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SecondViewController *secVC = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
[secVC saveData];
```

А в SecondViewController.h

```
- (void) saveData; //или  что там у вас...
```

Comment: экземпляр класса получаеться обязательно создавать? я хотел сразу на прямую SecondViewController ведь видит отлично, но метод не видит). Кароче спасибо! работает.